# CSS: Page content and background image getting cut off on mobile screen

Tags: css, screen, background-image, media

I am new to CSS and am looking for some help with the following.

I have an HTML page with the below structure at the beginning of its body. 
Inside the body I have a form with the class "`bgBanner`".

The idea with this is to set a background image only for the form but not for the rest of the body.

When viewing this on the desktop everything looks ok but when viewing it **on a mobile / smartphone everything gets cut off at the bottom edge of the screen** and I don't get a scrollbar there.

**Since I am new to this I guess one of my styles might overwrite another or I am using "overflow" the wrong way.** 
Can someone help me with this ?

**My HTML:**

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php require_once("includes/menu.php"); ?>
        <section id="main">
            <form id="frmLogin" class="bgBanner">
            <!-- ... -->
```

**My CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
form, #main {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#main {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 8.33%; /* col-1 */
    margin-right: 8.33%; /* col-1 */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bgBanner {
    background-image: url('../images/banner-M.jpg');
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

Many thanks for any help with this, 
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by removing the overflow from `form` and `#main` + by changing the CSS for `html` and `body` as follows:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This is working for me now on both desktop and mobile.
However, since I am new to this it might not be the best approach so if there are any comments please let me know.

Thanks !

Comment: Also take a look at this, its a great starting point  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBZYJ7QbN_c

Answer (score 2):

Use `#main {overflow-y: scroll}`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it doesn't change anything here. Any other thoughts ? :)

Comment: Yes, update with the rest of your HTML, I took a guess on what id to use but if I see all your html I can update it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that would be awesome. What other HTML do you need ? The rest is just the content of the form.

Comment: Never mind, I figured this out myself. Thanks anyways for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What did you need to change?

Comment: Just posted it as an answer. It might not be the perfect approach so please let me know if anything doesn't make sense - but it works.

Comment: Cool - thanks for your help ! With CSS I am still struggling a bit but things like this help a lot. :)